# Magento2 get ID of product in price template default.phtml

Tags: magento2, product, price, template, catalog

How can I get the ID of product in Magento 2, in tempalte

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml
```

I copied it to my theme:

```
/app/design/frontend/xxx/ddd/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Template is using block:

```
\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount
```

that has a method:

```
getSaleableItem()
```

that returns a `SaleableInterface` interface

that has a method:

```
getId()
```

so in your template you can do:

```
$block->getSaleableItem()->getId();
```